# Replace a value with a word inside the code and then paste it in a file, python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The code is generated to call a values from a file, if the 'I1, I2' value is equal to 1 it will replace it to animals, if the value is equal to 2 it will replace it to plants, if one of them is 1 and the other is 2 it should replace the 1 with animal and 2 with the plants 
And then paste the results in a new text file 
The problem is it doesnt do that.
Is there a way to replace I1 and I2 in items with the words

```
import sys
from scipy import interpolate
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import itertools
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from itertools import repeat


parametersAndValues = {}
parameterFile = open('ParameterValues') 

try:
    for line in parameterFile:
        parametersAndValues[line.split()[0]] = ((float(line.split()[1])))
finally:
    parameterFile.close()

for parameter in parametersAndValues:
    ( parameter + ' = ' + str(parametersAndValues.get(parameter)))

I1 = parametersAndValues.get('$I1')
I2 = parametersAndValues.get('$I2')


item = """WCONINJE
per1  I1  OPEN  RESV  1*  15000  7000 /
per2  I2  OPEN  RESV  1*  5000  7000  /
/
"""

for I  in item:
        for I in range(1,2):
                if I ==1:
                        line.replace("1", "animal")
                else:
                        line.replace("2", "plant")

with open('G3.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

with open('G3.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i,line in enumerate(lines):
        if i == 10:
                f.writelines(item) 

                ## End of Cycles
        else:
                f.write(line)
        previous_line = line
```

The output should looks like

If I1=1 and I2=2

```
per1  animal  OPEN  1*  5000  7000 /
per2  plant  OPEN  1*  5000  7000  /
/
```

If I1=2 and I2=1

```
per1  plant  OPEN  1*  5000  7000 /
per2  animal OPEN  1*  5000  7000  /
/
```

Comment: This isn't a [minimal, verifiable and complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but the following line looks suspicious - it doesn't do anything! `( parameter + ' = ' + str(parametersAndValues.get(parameter)))`

Comment: Can you show example of input and desired output?

Comment: @zipa, I added examples of what he outputs should looks like depending on the input